# Are Java Mockito mocked method invocations thread safe?

Tags: java, mockito

I am writing unit tests that test the thread safety of individual Java classes. I use Mocktio to set up the tests and verify the interactions in a multithreaded environment are done as per the expectations, and threads do not interfere with business expectations.

Are Mockito mocks thread-safe in that context? Can the mocked methods be called by many threads and the invocations will be counted correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are. Quoting [mockito documentation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ).

> (...) you can let multiple threads call methods on a shared mock to test in concurrent conditions.

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly.

Calling a method in parallel threads and counting times in ***Mockito.verify(..)*** may yield different results in each run.

Suppose we're testing the following call:

```
...
someListOfSize20.parallelStream().forEach(testedObject::methodToBeTested);
...
```

And try to verify:

```
Mockito.verify(testedObject, times(20)).methodToBeTested(any());
```

This tends to fail with different numbers of invocations on each run.

Here's the (still open) ticket about this:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1037

Comment: MockitoCore object created in the residing class of verify method is stored in static variable. Hence the problem I believe. It's surprising , given the omnipresence of Mockito. Probably  not many are using the parallel execution

Comment: that still seems to be an issue as of Mockito 4.5.1